# Conda doesn't find yml file when building virtrual environment

Tags: conda

I have created, on Win11 machine, the .yml files using:

```
conda env export > name1.yml
conda env export -f name2.yml --no-builds
conda env export -f name3.yml --from-history
```

and tried to build new virtual envs on Win Server 2012 R2 machine using:

```
conda create -n name -f name[x].yml
conda create -n name -f "Full_Address\name[x].yml"
```

All I got was error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
 - name[x].yml

Current channels:
 - https://repo.anaconda.com...
.
.
.
```

Same error shows when I try build the environment on the computer I built the yml file on.